# firebase cloud functions emulator erroring out

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using [firebase cloud functions emulator](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator). This is my folder scructure

```
├── firebase.json
├── functions
│   ├── etc
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── ArrayFromObject.ts
│   │   ├── Equations.ts
│   │   └── index.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── tslint.json
└── tree.txt
```

If I'm in the main folder, so on the level of `firebase.json` and run `sudo functions call helloWorld` I get this:

```
Error: { error:
{ code: 500,
    status: 'INTERNAL',
    message: 'Function worker crashed with exit code: 1\nundefinedWarning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Intializing firebase-admin may fail/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/supervisor/worker.js:80\n      throw new Error(`No function found with name ${cloudfunction.entryPoint || name}`);\n      ^\n\nError: No function found with name helloWorld\n    at process.on (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/supervisor/worker.js:80:13)\n    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)\n    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)\n    at emit (internal/child_process.js:772:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)',
    errors:
    [ 'Function worker crashed with exit code: 1\nundefinedWarning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Intializing firebase-admin may fail/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/supervisor/worker.js:80\n      throw new Error(`No function found with name ${cloudfunction.entryPoint || name}`);\n      ^\n\nError: No function found with name helloWorld\n    at process.on (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/supervisor/worker.js:80:13)\n    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)\n    at process.emit (events.js:214:7)\n    at emit (internal/child_process.js:772:12)\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)' ] } }
```

and I have no idea what's wrong here.

If I run sudo functions start I get this:

```
Google Cloud Functions Emulator RUNNING
┌────────┬────────────┬─────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Status │ Name       │ Trigger │ Resource                                               │
├────────┼────────────┼─────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ READY  │ helloWorld │ HTTP    │ http://localhost:5000/uczsieapp/us-central1/helloWorld │
└────────┴────────────┴─────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But if I go to this url I get

[image]

Same things happen if I try to run if from the `functions` directory

Here's my helloWorld code:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, resp) => {
    return 'hello';
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hey, I was just using the emulator a little while ago thanks to this [article](https://medium.com/@mwebler/debugging-firebase-functions-with-vs-code-3afab528bb36).  I too had a little trouble getting it up and running.  Try using `module.exports.helloWorld` instead of  `export const helloWorld`.  Also, run `functions deploy ...` from inside the functions subfolder instead of the firebase project root.  To connect the debugger, I had to use `functions inspect helloWorld` instead of `debug`.

Comment: if you have no intentions of debugging with VScode, then you can also serve the functions locally and debug print to the console.  Instead of using `functions` you use:  `firebase serve --only functions` in the root of your project.  This will fireup http triggers you can test with your browser pretty easily.